# Rational Functional Tester and mock framework

Tags: unit-testing, user-interface, mocking

I am evaluating different options (tools, framework) that are available for unit-testing my GUI code. Our GUI is combination of SWT/Swing components. Among couple of options that we have evaluated is Rational Functional Tester (others that we'd evaluated are SWTBot, Jubula etc.). RFT(Rational Functional Tester) seems to satisfy most of our needs. My question is - can we use any mocking framework (like EasyMock, PowerMock, JMock etc.) with RFT ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools - Did you check   Squish .. that was more economical  when i checked last time.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - it will work. RFT does not really assume any thing from application. Some of the lookups it creates will use classnames; if you are using find using properties (or name) then this will not affect you.

Long answer -

Using RFT for unit testing GUI is not a good idea. It is more useful when you want to test application as such (a full system test for example).  Consider using real unit testing framework like [uispec4j](http://www.uispec4j.org/) or [FEST](http://code.google.com/p/fest/)